# the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef

Tags: scala

I develop a case class in scala 2.11.8 like this:

```
case class MyClass(nameAttribute: String, get: () => Object)
```

I can't replace Object in the second parameter, since i place functions with differents return type.
If I instanciate this line I get the error in the title:

```
MyClass("MyAttribute_Long", () => 1l)
```

I get two errors for this line:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Long(1L)
 required: Object
              MyClass("MyAttribute_Long", () => 1l),
```

and

```
the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
              MyClass("MyAttribute_Long", () => 1l),
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI the Scala equivalent of Object is AnyRef. You can use a type parameter in your case.

```
case class MyClass[T](nameAttribute: String, get: () => T)
```